# Is there a way to use projectile to specify the compilation directory with a cmake project?

Tags: emacs, projectile

Using the projectile package with emacs in a cmake project, I have a .projectile file in the project root.  When I type C-c C-p c, it wants to run "cmake --build ." in the root directory.  I'd like it to go to {project root}/build and run cmake.  I have tried a .dir-local.el with:

(
 ( nil . (
          (projectile-compilation-dir . "./build"))))

specified - no luck.  Any hints?  My google searches aren't turning up anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So - I made a mistake - .dir-local**s**.el, then it worked.  Sorry everyone - hope this helps someone else....